# Can multiple individuals contribute non-spell prerequisites during item creation?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, crafting

Robert, a 3rd level human druid possessing the feat *Craft Wondrous Item*, desires to make *Boots of Striding and Springing* (*DMG* p.251). However, he lacks the necessary 5 ranks in Jump called for in the prerequisites of the item. His friend, a 3rd level orc barbarian named Arnold, is very talented at jumping - possessing over the necessary 5 ranks.

Whilst the item creation rules do support multiple casters contributing toward the spell prerequisites of an item (*Ibid.,* p.282), are there any printed rules which allow for non-spell item prerequisites to be contributed toward item creation by individuals other than the individual possessing *Craft Wondrous Item*?

If such supplemental rules do exist, where are those rules?

---

Note: I was able to find and retrieve [this](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20041207a/) "Rules of the Game" article which seems to answer my question, I am unable to find any printed material that iterates what S. Williams says<sup>1</sup> in this source. Is this a holdover from 3e?

<sup>1: "Two or more characters can work together to create an item, with each character providing one or more prerequisites."</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike the *Dungeon Master's Guide* that in its [Creating Magic Items](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#creating-magic-items) section (282) seems to emphasize meeting *only* spell prerequisites with assistance, the *Magic Item Compendium* on Crafting Magic Items says

> All items have prerequisites in their descriptions. These prerequisites must be met for the item to be created. Most of the time, they take the form of feats and spells that the item’s creator must know, although access through another magic item or spellcaster is allowed. **It’s perfectly acceptable for two or more characters to work together to create a magic item, with each character supplying some of the prerequisites.** (232)

(Emphasis mine.) While the sentence previous to the the boldfaced sentence focuses on meeting feat and spell prerequisites, the boldfaced sentence seems to imply strongly that *any* creature can assist a creator in meeting a magic item's creation prerequisites if the creature's willing to participate in the creation process, much like Williams says in the Rules of the Game column ["Making Magic Items (Part One)."](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20041207a/)

By way of personal experience, this DM allows nonspellcasters to assist in the creation of magic items by helping the creator meet [unusual magic](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#boat-folding) [item prerequistes](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#dwarven-thrower), and his campaigns don't explode because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I Can Chan's post provides the meat and potatoes of the answer so no need to repeat that here. But I'd like to sweeten the deal by providing the desert that compliments his answer!

---

What is the worst part about crafting? It's not the gold, not the time and not even the feats, no it's the XP!!  Crafting can quickly drain enough XP to cause the crafter's power level to constantly lag behind the party! Now not only does the fighter have his awesome +2 Flaming Tridant of Returning but he's also a level (or more) higher!

Fear Not!! Since your using wizard's web articles they also have a way for us to share the XP cost as well!!  Doing this is not as simple as providing the spell/skill requirements are but there are multiple ways that make sharing XP costs with up to **5 willing**  creatures possible!

Note: The below article is titled "PHB2 Part1 but I dont see anything in the actual printed PHB2 about this. Follow the link for the specific details on how to do so.
http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060526a

Comment: I can't access the page that link is for. Are you perhaps referring to the first level spell "transference" from the player handbook 2, and the "ritual of transference?"